# Как проверить, включена ли поддержка сокетов?

Tags: php

Как проверить, включена ли поддержка сокетов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`PHP:get_loaded_extensions`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.get-loaded-extensions.php) 
возвращает массив имен всех скомпилированных и загруженных в PHP интерпретаторе модулей.

```
if ( in_array( "sockets", get_loaded_extensions() ) ) {
    // ...
}
```

[`PHP:extension_loaded`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.extension-loaded.php)
Определяет, загружено ли указанное расширение.

```
if ( extension_loaded( "sockets" ) ) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @ReinRaus, добавьте еще: extension_loaded и function_exists для полноты ответа. Мало информации в интернете, с ходу не нашел. Спасибо.

Comment: z668, ок, добавил `extension_loaded`. `function_exists` слабее связана с темой топика.